# MySQLi remote connection host:port

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have access to a remote Mysql database with the adress host:port.

It works fine to access the database server with a Mysql client (DBeaver).

I am trying to connect to the same database server with PHP.

```
<?php
    
    $host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3333";    
    $port = 3306;
    $user = "user";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "db01";

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

?>
```

The port 3333 is used by the router for port forwarding to access the server from outside.

I get:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 
'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3333' (25)
```

Is it possible that we can't use "host:port" in $host entry in mysqli?

Do I have to use an IP address without a port?

Comment: SO which port is it 3333 or 3306?

Comment: Take the port OFF the `$host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3333"; ` So remove 3333. Then if the port IS 3333 place that in the variable `$port` or whatever port you want to go to

Comment: No, mysql server uses the standard port 3306. But the server host has the IP adress "92.35.184.250:3333"

Comment: "92.35.184.250:3333" is not an IP address, it is an IP address and port number.

Comment: Ok, this means that we can't use 92.35.184.250:3333.

Comment: Probably I need to use a reverse proxy to solve the problem.

Comment: I think you need to remove the 3333 as what @RiggsFolly said. Is it working after you remove it and put the 3333 on the $port variable?

Comment: Try with just `92.35.184.250`. you said yourself the database port is 3306 so it's not clear why you tried 3333 instead. Maybe that port runs some other service on that machine?

Comment: No, the $port variable is used by Mysql server e.g ($port = 3306). the port 3333 is used by the router for port forwarding to access the server from outside.

Comment: But you said 3306 works with dbeaver? Are you using that from inside the network? Anyway in that case as others said you need to specify the 3333 in the separate port option of the mysqli command, not as part of the IP

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php shows you how to set the parameters including the port

Answer (score 2):

Mysqli allows you to specify the port parameter in two ways. Either as part of the host parameter after the colon, e.g. `127.0.0.1:3306`, or as the fifth (port) parameter. When the port is provided together with the hostname, the value provided in the hostname parameter takes precedence over whatever port is specified in the port parameter.